# Is it safe to work on object that delete later was called on

Tags: c++, qt

I was thinking about writing method like this:

```
QString getData() {
    QNetworkReply *reply = getReply();
    reply->deleteLater();
    return QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll()).trimmed();
}
```

Is it safe?
If I'm forced to write this like this:

```
QString getData() {
    QNetworkReply *reply = getReply();
    QString result = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll()).trimmed();
    reply->deleteLater();
    return result;
}
```

I'm copping QString twice (am I?, once it's put into result and second when returning it by value), which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: How is `deleteLater` going to work?

Comment: @sftrabbit He's using Qt, so he's not the one defining the method.

Comment: @AntonieBlom Ah, I didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [deleteLater](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater) docs:

> Schedules this object for deletion.
>
> The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop. If the event loop is not running when this function is called (e.g. deleteLater() is called on an object before QCoreApplication::exec()), the object will be deleted once the event loop is started.

So what you are doing there is safe. Obviously handing out references or pointers to that object (or its members) that might be persisted is wrong. But if you're returning copies, you're fine.

But what you're doing might or might not do what you want to do. `readAll` doesn't block, it returns the data *currently available*. Meaning that a single call to `readAll` might only read a partial response - unless you've ensured that all data has arrived through other means.

Other things to note, from the docs:

> Note that entering and leaving a new event loop (e.g., by opening a modal dialog) will not perform the deferred deletion; for the object to be deleted, the control must return to the event loop from which deleteLater() was called.

So the only thing to worry about when doing this type of thing would be calling functions that somehow re-enters the "current" event loop. But that won't happen if that is done via [`QCoreApplication::processEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents):

> In event you are running a local loop which calls this function continuously, without an event loop, the DeferredDelete events will not be processed.

So that's covered too. The deferred deletion logic is pretty complex, but safe under normal circumstances. If you're digging very deep into the Qt internals (or calling code that might do something fishy there), be defensive. But for normal code flow, `deleteLater` is safe as long as you don't have dangling references (or pointers) that might persist.

Answer (score 0):

What does `deleteLater` do?  From it's name, I would expect that it registers the object for deletion at some later point in time (end of transaction? end of session?).  If so, you can safely use it as long as that later point in time has not occurred.  The only issue is knowing when that point occurs, but for things like end of transaction or end of session, you're probably safe—if your function was called within a transaction or session, the transaction or session will not end until you return.

Comment: `deleteLater` is a member function of `QObject`.

Answer (score -1):

It is safe, but you'd better not use `deleteLater` at all, because

> The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop. If
>   the event loop is not running when this function is called (e.g.
>   deleteLater() is called on an object before QCoreApplication::exec()),
>   the object will be deleted once the event loop is started.

means that object can be deleted mmm... never. This pretend to work like GC, but it is even worse:

```
class A: public QObject
{
    char x[10000000];
};

void process()
{
    A* a = new A();
    //delete a;
    a->deleteLater();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    for (int k = 0; k < 1000000; ++k) {
        process();
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

At least it is not C++ idiomatic, that uses RAII.

From the other size, copying `QString` is a cheap operation, because `QSring` uses copy-on-write ideome.

Comment: You're mis-reading the docs. Stick a destructor in `A` that outputs something, you'll see it gets called when `exec` starts. From the quote: "the object **will be deleted** once the event loop is started."

Comment: @Mat, this example will generate bad alloc before `a.exec` is executed. It is syntactic example, but the problem of accumulating hung-objects (and hung resources) inside single event loop exists. Problem of 'unexpectedly finished event processing' (with `QTHread`, for example) also exists.

Comment: Sure there can be problems in some circumstances. Your sample doesn't demonstrate one though. If you think that code dying is a bug in `deleteLater`, it is not, it is a mis-use of it. It behaves as documented.

Comment: @Mat, I'm not telling that there is some bug in `deleteLater`, but using `deleteLater` often smells.

Comment: @Lol4t0 This is a classical pattern in transaction processing; in this case, QT is simply treating the event loop like a transaction (which, when you think about it, makes a lot of sense).

Comment: @JamesKanze, to be a transaction, even loop should satisfy some transaction properties, and I don't see how it "must succeed or fail as a complete unit; it cannot remain in an intermediate state." (from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing))